# Error compiling maven using solr 6.0.0

Tags: java, maven, solr, osgi

I'm making a plugin in a OSGi environment and for some reason I cant use any higher version than Solr 4.3.1. If I add the dependency for solr-core 6.0.0 and sorl-solrj 6.0.0 I get a ton of errors when running mvn clean install. Here are the
[maven output](https://groups.google.com/group/cytoscape-helpdesk/attach/2afd310294a30/mvndump.txt?part=0.1&authuser=0&view=1)
and [pom.xml](https://groups.google.com/group/cytoscape-helpdesk/attach/2afd310294a30/pom.xml?part=0.2&authuser=0&view=1)

I've used solr 4.3.1 successfully but cant get maven to compile the project when using 6.0.0. I don't understand whats wrong and I've used many days trying to figure this out, but with no luck. Any help would be much appreciated :)

I'm using java-8-openjdk-amd64 and maven 3.3.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the problem. Upgrading the maven-bundle-plugin to version 3.0.1 fixed it.